# Use component with additional static property with React + Flow?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have approximately this code:

```
/* @flow */

import * as React from 'react';

const Foo = () => null;
Foo.bar = null;

const Bar: React.ComponentType<{}> & { bar: any } = Foo;

const Baz = ({ children } : { children: React.Node }) => children;

<Baz><Bar /></Baz>
```

Actually, the static property is being assigned using the Recompose `setStatic` HOC, but the end result is the same.

My problem is that this code will make Flow throw the [following error](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBLAtgBzgJwBdkwBDAZzACUBTUgY2KnzizAHJ87H2BudenAB25YgDE4cMAF4wACgCUMgHxghAVxgx+EuADoARqXwy1m7QOGiwAIWMAuat0J6AwqzxCaQwgBUAnjg0ADwA3gC+qgBkYKFgRviOpEL+YOGmuvyogiLEdgBepnJx9AAWGDAAJlxCaWCOJeVVNY60DC4AcnCVNGlK0qplFdXeWcEFyuPGYMCTwBNAA):

```
12: <Baz><Bar /></Baz>
         ^ Cannot create `Bar` element because object type [1] is not a React component.
References:
8: const Bar: React.ComponentType<{}> & { bar: any } = Foo;
                                        ^ [1]
```

How can I change my type annotations to make Flow happy?

Comment: Looks like a regression starting from 0.70.0 version.

Comment: Thanks @AlekseyL., Flow has a long record of broken features that could have been called regression but that actually are "intended"... I wonder if this is one of them.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at change log, but couldn't find something related. Maybe I'm missing something..